# Error using SoapClient() in PHP

Tags: soap, php

I'm trying to access WSDL(Web Service Definition Language) file using SoapClient() of PHP. I found that WSDL file is authenticated. I tried with passing credentials on an array by another parameter and active SSL on my server, still I'm getting an error.

Here is the code I'm using:

> $client = new
>   SoapClient("https://webservices.chargepointportal.net:8081/coulomb_api_1.1.wsdl",array("trace"
>   => "1","Username" => "username","Password" => "password"));

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Warning:
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(https://webservices.chargepointportal.net:8081/coulomb_api_1.1.wsdl)
>   [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
>   in PATH_TO_FILE on line 80
>
> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://webservices.chargepointportal.net:8081/coulomb_api_1.1.wsdl"
>   in PATH_TO_FILE on line 80
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://webservices.chargepointportal.net:8081/coulomb_api_1.1.wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://webservices.chargepointportal.net:8081/coulomb_api_1.1.wsdl"
>   in PATH_TO_FILE:80 Stack trace: #0
>   /home2/wingstec/public_html/widget/API/index.php(80):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('https://webserv...', Array) #1 {main} thrown
>   in PATH_TO_FILE on line 80

It seems that error says file not exist at the path we given but when we run that path directly on browser then we're getting that file

Can anyone help me to figure out what the exactly problem is?

Comment: Hi Initall, Please don't close the question as I'm just sharing an issue what I'm getting. Its important for me to get solution as I can't figure out the exact issue. Can you tell me why I'm getting this error or where I'm going wrong with the process.

Comment: @Dhaval This question doesn't even belong here, but at StackOverflow. If you disagree with their closing of it, then petition to have it re-opened *over there*. Don't just go posting it other places hoping to trick someone into addressing it; we'd only migrate it over to SO anyway. [Voting to close.]

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have the right to access website from your hosting account or server - check first if you can access a http webservice (without the *s*). If not, check if allow_url_fopen is set to true in php.ini.

Then, if you are trying to establish a https connection, you need a local certificate. 
See if you can add one and instantiate your Soap object using something like

```
new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $pathToLocalCert));
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, I'm able to access http webservice. I'm new to use SoapClient() and I don't know about any certificate. About which certificate you are talking abouut?

Comment: The SSL certificate - similar to the one your browser uses when accessing a https website. You can find a short explanation on http://roman.tao.at/dev/php/php-soapclient-over-https-with-pkcs12-p12-certificates/, but googling "php soap ssl certificate" will give you heaps of information. It *is* a bit complicated, but can be managed.

Comment: Hi Olaf, I've removed port number from the URL and its working to remove error but still confused to access about using its methods. As I'm new to using this I don't know how to access its method. I tried few methods but throwing an error.

Comment: Dhaval, it's hard to tell without code and details. However, you are on the right path, and you just have to learn it, maybe using a clean setup and a tutorial.